# Beginner revoked all his certificates trying to fix the "10 apps in 7 days" error

Tags: ios, certificate, app-store, app-store-connect

So some background info...

My main development machine is an imac that had functioning certificates and provisioning files.  At the time, I revoked my certificates using my macbook attempting to fix the "10 apps in 7 days" error, which did not have any certificates or profiles downloaded to it.  So I began playing with my xcode account after briefly reading suggestions to fix this error, well, I made a few mistakes haha.

The day after making these mis-opportune decisions, I revoked the following: Mac  Installer Distribution, IOS Development, Mac App Distribution, Mac Development, and IOS distribution certificates from my macbook (and I assume my iMac as well?).

With that in mind, I'm lost as to how to proceed.  I contacted apple directly, unfortunately they only offer administratic support.  I've read through a number of past questions here about re-installing certificiates - some say that the process is rather automatic because of xcode and other answers suggest deleting and creating new certificates through itunes connect/member center.

With that in mind, would someone be able to recommend a course of action regarding these certificates on both iMac and Macbook?  Also, Will I have to re-do/make changes to my one currently live app?

Answer (score 2):

With a feeling of "this can't get much worse", I played around and fixed my problem.  My first step, I went into my keychain access - my certificates.  I deleted all the certificates; xcode will replace the proper certificates.  My next step was to delete all my provisioning files in the apple developer member center.  From there, I created 2 new provisioning profiles (at least for the one app I have live); one for iphone development and one for app store distribution.  I went through the provisioning profile creation steps, downloaded both files, and then double-clicked both files (Both will become part of your xcode account identity).  With that, my app was able to download onto my test iphone 6.  Unfortunately to finish this process, I had to enter this code into the terminal

```
rm -rf "$(getconf DARWIN_USER_CACHE_DIR)/org.llvm.clang/ModuleCache"
rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData
rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/com.apple.dt.Xcode
```

If you're unlucky like me, you will get an error in xcode as your app launches along the lines of "no image was found".  Thankfully this code snippet fixes that dilemma.